# Django: Is a user without a password safe?

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm trying to create an interactive website  with Django for a chat bot. I have a model that stores the chat logs, `ChatLogs`. It has two fields: `sender` and `message`. `sender`, as the name might suggest, is a foreign key denoting who the sender of `message` is. It can be either the bot or a user. Here's how I have it set up:

```py
class ChatLogs(models.Model):
  sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  message = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Since the sender can be the bot or a user, I thought to create a record in the `User` table for the bot:

```py
$ python3 manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> User.objects.create_user("Bot")
```

I created the user without a password because, according to the Django documentation for `createsuperuser`, an account created as such can't be used to login. Which I think is a secure way to handle this. My question is, is there any reason I should not be doing this?
From the Django documentation (for [createsuperuser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#createsuperuser)):

> When run non-interactively, you can provide a password by setting the DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD environment variable. Otherwise, no password will be set, and the superuser account will not be able to log in until a password has been manually set for it.